# TEXT FORMAT LOST

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I had to edit an illustrator file, a menu for a restaurant that needed some changes in the texts.

When opening the Ai file provided I found that the text boxes/blocks are not boxes anymore, but instead single separated lines and even single characters (they're editable, not curves)

Do you guys know why this happens?

[image: TEXT FORMAT LOST]